# Confirming graphics card choice for Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Do you know if the following graphics card will work with Gazebo?

**NVIDIA QUADRO 4000**

It has memory bandwidth of 89.6 GB/s.

Do you what specs I should meet? The specs for the NVIDIA QUADRO 4000 are located here:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadro-4000-us.html

Thanks very much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3712/confirming-graphics-card-choice-for-gazebo/) by [mchapman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/405/mchapman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From Jesper on the mailing list:

"We have a bunch of computers with the Quadro 4000 running Gazebo, so it will work. However, it won't be as fast as a recent geforce (consumer cards tend to be faster)."

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mchapman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/405/mchapman/) on 2013-07-23**:
Thanks very much for your help!